# Making an SQL prodedure to add characters to a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I'm trying to make a procedure in SQL that adds a bunch of zeroes to a string to complete its length to 18 characters for example:

`0446793932' ====> '000000000446793932`

and this procedure would go inside an update command,

`UPDATE Table SET variable = prototype_procedure('0446793932') WHERE .......`

I don't know much about SQL or procedures, if anyone could guide me through something that could help me understand, I would appreciate,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use REPLICATE function to achieve what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx

```
DECLARE @t NVARCHAR(10) = N'0446793932'
SELECT @t, REPLICATE(N'0', 18 - LEN(@t)) + @t
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on what language you are using along the SQL, your best bet is to just add the characters to the string before you send the data to database, that way you don't risk screwing up your tables.

I would using something like this in php for example:

```
$myvar = "123456";
$myvarLength = strlen($myvar);
if($myvarLength < 12){
     while{$myvarLength != 12){
         $myvar = "0".$myvar;
         $myvarlength = strlen($myvar);
     }
}
```

This should get the job done for you

Comment: According to the tags he's using MSSQL, and it's capable of converting the data more efficiently. There's absolutely no need to read all the data from the database, read it in PHP and send it back, SQL can do the conversion by it self much much faster.

Comment: I don't work with mssql much, so I'm not 100% familiar capabilities, but that is useful information to know! Thank you Fedor!